# How do I configure Ethernet on Raspbian 10 (buster)?

Tags: dhcp, internet

Updated with more diagnostics:

I have a Rpi3b with Raspbian 10 (buster), installed from an openplotter headless image (https://openplotter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/downloading.html).

It is nicely controllable by Remote Desktop from my Win10 box through cabled network. **However, I cannot connect the PI to Internet**.

From my Win10 box, I can ping the RPi3b by its name and by its IPv6 (time <=1ms), but not by its IPv4 (Request timed out). From the Rpi3b, pinging my Win10 box by its IP4 gives Destination Host Unreachable, by its IPv6 gives Destination unreachable: Address unreachable; and pinging by the Win10 host name gives an error message in Norwegian translating to 'Temporary error in name lookup'.

I have tried both with and without setting a static ip in etc/dhcpcd.conf. SD card is tested and writable OK. Various troubleshooting attempts indicate that I do not have ca-certificates installed, and that the system time is several days off. Without Internet, updates are not on the menu. The Rpi3b is connected to the same switch and router as the Win10 box I am sending this from.

Logging in to my Internet provider, I can see all devices on my network, and the router indeed lists the RPi3b with its name, IPv4 address, and MAC address (which correctly expands to the Rpi3b's IPv6 address according to https://ben.akrin.com/?p=1347).

I have tried to force my router's address into the Rpi3b:

```
pi@openplotter:~ $ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.10.1
```

which did not bring me any further.

I have poor Linux experience, and don't know what to look for in config files.

Does anyone have a suggestion for what to try next?

netstat -rn and ifconfig -a provides the following info:

```
pi@openplotter:~ $ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 br0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0

pi@openplotter:~ $ ifconfig -a
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.10.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.10.10.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe97:661f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:97:66:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 25895  bytes 1811918 (1.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2437  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 31913  bytes 36337920 (34.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.111  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe97:661f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:97:66:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 28035  bytes 2135868 (2.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 37403  bytes 36916030 (35.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8247  bytes 745742 (728.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8247  bytes 745742 (728.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan9: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fec2:334a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:c2:33:4a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8349  bytes 932028 (910.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0



pi@openplotter:~ $ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:97:66:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.111/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 80819sec preferred_lft 80819sec
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe97:661f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:97:66:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.1/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe97:661f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:c2:33:4a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fec2:334a/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
pi@openplotter:~ $
```

On my Win10 box, I run:

```
C:\Users\SjurK>arp -a

Interface: 192.168.10.138 --- 0x6
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  10.10.10.1            b8-27-eb-97-66-1f     dynamic
  169.254.118.238       b8-27-eb-97-66-1f     dynamic
  192.168.10.1          a0-e4-cb-24-d7-c2     dynamic
  192.168.10.111        b8-27-eb-97-66-1f     dynamic
  192.168.10.139        6c-2f-2c-9c-2c-58     dynamic
  192.168.10.150        dc-71-44-5c-7c-43     dynamic
  192.168.10.181        b0-6e-bf-ba-78-f7     dynamic
  192.168.10.198        b8-27-eb-97-66-1f     dynamic
  192.168.10.199        00-26-b9-e7-07-8f     dynamic
  192.168.10.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

C:\Users\SjurK>
```

The similar command on the RPi3b gives:

```
pi@openplotter:~ $ arp   
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.10.1                     (incomplete)                              eth0
10.10.10.151                     (incomplete)                              br0
10.10.10.112                     (incomplete)                              br0
192.168.10.138                   (incomplete)                              eth0
192.168.10.138           ether   a4:4c:c8:95:ce:45   C                     br0
10.10.10.182             ether   c8:93:46:32:19:9d   C                     br0
pi@openplotter:~ $
```

The (incomplete) suggests a route to explore, but the arp command was new to me today and have no idea on what and where to edit in order to provide the missing info. Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Update: I can now ping my RPi3b by its hostname from my Win10 laptop, and I get reply from an IP6 address which is listed under br0: when i do ifconfig on the RPi3b.

Comment: I can also see the RPi3b on my home router's list of connected devices. It displays the IP4 address I have now set as static on the RPi3b, and a Mac address I also recognise from RPi3b-ifconfig, this time under eth0:. From the RPi3b I can ping the four addresses shown by ifconfig (variants of 'myself', I guess), but nothing else, neither by name nor by IP.